# Is it illegal to publicly reveal security flaws in a service?

Tags: web-application, web-service

Mainly I'm interested in UK law on this, but I welcome input from any jurisdiction.

I discovered flaws in a service that undermined the security of all its user's data. This is a service where users are billed for usage. The flaw, if exploited would allow hackers to make charges to user's accounts.

I disclosed this flaw responsibly to the site owner. The site owner thanked me but played down the seriousness of the flaw, like "oh sure, you *could* do that, but it's never happened before". The site owner has shown no intention of fixing this, in fact the most recent update has introduced another similar flaw.

This flaw comes ultimately from a lack of knowledge on a developer's part, I want to publish this incident on my blog with details of how to *not* do the same thing in order to educate others.

Could I be breaking the law by doing that?

Comment: Also interesting to know does the site owner brakes the law, knowingly ignore the security flaw risking users' data?

Comment: I don't think its illegal, but unethical. If you're a programmer than you know you have bugs in your software and you would want someone who finds them to tell you first and wait until you can fix them.

Comment: @matejkramny that's exactly what I did and they didn't care. It was over 12 months since I disclosed this.

Comment: @MattHarrison try telling them that you will publish this flaw, leak it to newspapers etc. Then they will care to fix it..

Comment: While IT Security and the Law frequently intersect each other, this website is not intended to provide legal counsel or advice for anyone. With that said, if you're *really* interested in the legality of this, I would hope you wouldn't put your faith in free advice obtained from the internet to keep you out of legal trouble.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES I wouldn't say I was seeking legal counsel. It's just casual curiosity at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to educate other people on how to secure their site more effectively, i can see no harm in that as long as you do not mention the vulnerable site at all or even hint at it.

A number of sites detail how to perform exploits and how to secure yourself, but they never encourage users to do anything illegal or post targets because that's what gets the police involved.

If you still want to post it on a blog, i **strongly** suggest you see a lawyer.

Comment: I think that's a reasonable and mature suggestion. I will follow your recommendations.